# Merge two Dataframe based on Column that contains name and surname but in different order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that has a column with name and surname but in one of them is in different order, in the first one is name surname order and in the second one surname name order.

How can I do the merge by ignoring the order of the `name` column?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Dominik Hull D',
                            'Lulu Castaneda',
                            'Zachary Pearce',
                            'Paul Lewis',
                            'Neave Potts',
                            'Ruth Callahan',
                            'Evelyn Haney W',
                            'Julie Mclaughlin',
                            'Kaleb Hardin',
                            'Kayleigh Little',
]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Mclaughlin Julie',
                            'Hardin Kaleb',
                            'Hull D Dominik',
                            'Castaneda Lulu',
                            'Callahan Ruth',
                            'Haney W Evelyn',
                            'Pearce Zachary',
                            'Lewis Paul',
                            'Potts Neave',
                            'Little Kayleigh',
], 'value':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

new_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name', how='left')
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange `name` column in `df2` *on the fly* (with [`pd.Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)):

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2.assign(name=df2['name'].
                                  str.rsplit(n=1).str[::-1].str.join(' ')),
                  on='name', how='left')
```

---

```
               name  value
0    Dominik Hull D      2
1    Lulu Castaneda      3
2    Zachary Pearce      6
3        Paul Lewis      7
4       Neave Potts      8
5     Ruth Callahan      4
6    Evelyn Haney W      5
7  Julie Mclaughlin      0
8      Kaleb Hardin      1
9   Kayleigh Little      9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add temporary columns to `df1`/`df2` where you convert the names to `fronzeset` and then merge according this column:

```py
df1['tmp'] = df1['name'].apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.split()))
df2['tmp'] = df2['name'].apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.split()))

new_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='tmp', how='left').drop(columns='tmp')
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
             name_x            name_y  value
0    Dominik Hull D    Hull D Dominik      2
1    Lulu Castaneda    Castaneda Lulu      3
2    Zachary Pearce    Pearce Zachary      6
3        Paul Lewis        Lewis Paul      7
4       Neave Potts       Potts Neave      8
5     Ruth Callahan     Callahan Ruth      4
6    Evelyn Haney W    Haney W Evelyn      5
7  Julie Mclaughlin  Mclaughlin Julie      0
8      Kaleb Hardin      Hardin Kaleb      1
9   Kayleigh Little   Little Kayleigh      9
```